# Can't run or debug react native

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, genymotion

I am using Visual Code, and just created an react native app through `create-react-app NewTest`
I already installed React Native Tools in vscode
The app is running just fine in my android device through Expo installed on it. The problem is that I can't run it on my simulator which is genymotion mobile
I get this error:
[Error] Error: Unknown error: not all success patterns were matched

My `launch.json`:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug Android",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "android",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug iOS",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "ios",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to packager",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "attach",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug in Exponent",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "exponent",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
        }
    ]
}
```

I just started the [getting started](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native) tutorial and I have no idea about why it is not working. I already search over the internet and could not find much help.

[Genymotion device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aovCA.jpg)

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCgD7.jpg)

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/624

Comment: Then looks like the bug was not solved yet.